# How to get rid of HP Device Monitor?

Tags: macos, printing, monterey

HP Device Monitor is using 40-50% CPU time. I've read on numerous sites that this isn't needed, and I should use HP Uninstaller or HP Easy Start to uninstall it. I don't have UP Uninstaller -- there's no HP or Hewlett Packard folder in Applications. I tried downloading HP Easy Start from 123.hp.com/setup, but when I run it the "Uninstall HP Support" option is greyed out.

The only HP software I can find on my machine is the HP Smart application. I thought the older HP software was uninstalled when I installed that (not sure when that was). Would removing that get rid of HP Device Monitor?

`top -o cpu` shows:

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS             %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS     COW     MSGSENT    MSGRECV
4496   HP Device Mo 38.3 18:43.70 22/1  10/1 526-  31M-   0B     13M    4496  1     running  *0[1]              0.00000 0.00000    505  49002+     641     880753+    415130+
```

There are actually two HP Device Monitor processes. One with my username and about 40% CPU, and another with username `admin` and 0%.

In the past I've usually been able to get it to slow down for a while by quitting it from Activity Monitor. But now it comes back and goes back to the high CPU level.

I suspect part of the problem is that I have an M1 MacBook but this is an Intel process.

Comment: Can you get some information about the process name in Activity Monitor, or by running `top -o cpu`?

Comment: The Monitor is at `/Library/Printers/hp/Frameworks/HPDeviceMonitoring.framework/Versions/1.0/Helpers/HP Device Monitor Manager.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/HP Device Monitor.app` [note that's deep inside an app, itself inside a framework, so be carful] Mine is using 14MB RAM & 0% CPU

Comment: @nohillside I've added the top output and added some more information.

Comment: Well, you can always change file permissions to 000 and kill the running process.

Comment: @nohillside That worked. :) Want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three more options to reduce the nuisance of HP Device Monitor:

The cleanest way would be probably option 1:

1. Another way to disable HP Device Monitor cleanly via launchd is:

   ```
   launchctl disable    user/501/disable com.hp.devicemonitor
   ```

   with of course "501" being your actual userid…

   After the above command the app will still be running, but terminating it in this launchd state will prevent it from respawning. On next reboot it will not load.

   Undo this, if you feel it necessary with

   ```
   launchctl enable    user/501/disable com.hp.devicemonitor
   ```

   This command doesn't need sudo, as the plist is in a user-owned directory. This format is a per the now recent help of `man launchctl` (since many here might expect something along the lines of the still working but legacy `unload` subcommand)

This leads us to two further possibilities:

2. The launchctl plist file is at

   ```
   $ /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.devicemonitor.plist
   ```

   Simply deleting it (or moving out of this folder temporarily/for testing purposes; it may be used for FAX for something like that).
3. Similar to @nohillside's answer, at

   You may also just delete the entire program at the root-level Library folder:

   ```
   sudo rm -r  '/Library/Printers/hp/Frameworks/HPDeviceMonitoring.framework/Versions/1.0/Helpers/HP Device Monitor Manager.app/'
   ```

---

If CLI/Terminal commands are not your thing, software like for example [SomaZone's LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) will make it much easier to issue your will…

Comment: Thanks, option 1 seems cleanest and I've done that.

Comment: @Barmar Well, honestly, this is only somewhat clean, albeit a bit arcane. There would be a few more options needed still for a _really 'clean'_ state of things: 1. Apple providing a reliable and well documented _GUI_ for that 2. HP better documenting its stuff & make it behave (CPU usage is ridiculous, plain purpose of that Monitor obscure) 3. HP making this 'option' slectable via a GUI to 'run _optionally'_

Comment: In option 3, you need to use `rm -r` since it's a directory.

Comment: Is the "Undo this" command correct? It is shown as being the same as the disable command.

Answer (score 3):

- Run `sudo chmod 000 '/Library/Printers/hp/Frameworks/HPDeviceMonitoring.framework/Versions/1.0/Helpers/HP Device Monitor Manager.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/HP Device Monitor.app'`
- Kill the running process

The `chmod` takes away the access rights required for a restart of the process.

PS: not sure what the process actually does, so watch out for side effects.

Comment: Well, I successfully printed this web page after killing it. And I was able to view ink levels, open the printer utility, etc. So so far, so good.